# iOS and Cocos2d: my app REALLY slow on simulator but is FINE on device

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

..I am wondering whether there is some setting I should change to get my iOS 5.0 app running fine on an iPhone IOS 5.0 simulator. It runs at only 12fps instead on my device runs at 60fps. Any help? I would have expected the simulator to work fine..

I am using XCode 4.3 and Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Comment: In my experience, the Simulator is faster in terms of CPU speed, but significantly slower when it comes to graphics performance. Since your app seems to be graphics-oriented, that could explain your issue.

Comment: Thats normal, nobody but you will be playing it on a simulator =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simulator performance is completely and utterly irrelevant. The Simulator runs on your Mac's CPU, that's multiple times faster than the fastest iOS device. The Simulator does however not use hardware graphics accelerations, so it's easily maxed out even though your Mac is so much faster. Lastly, which of your app's users are going to run your app on the Simulator? Answer: no one!

That said, there is still reason to be alarmed. You get 60 fps on the device, that's great. But which device? If it is an iPhone 4S or iPad 3, that device is a lot faster than older devices like iPhone 3GS (or even older yet) or iPad 1. So depending on which device is the oldes device you're developing for, you might still have a problem. Try to find or borrow such a device, and test it on that oldest-supported device, and do test only with a release build.

Consider the facts:

- Simulator performance sucks
- Retina Simulator performance sucks even more
- iPad Retina Simulator performance is beyond good & android
- You're most likely the only person ever to run your app in the iOS Simulator

Therefore:

- Simulator performance is irrelevant
- Simulator performance can not be compared to device performance
- *The Simulator* is for quicker testing of your app's business logic, nothing else. Not even Samsung copied it.

In addition:

- Debug build performance is largely irrelevant. At least verify performance measurements in release builds.
- Test on oldest supported device. Otherwise you have no way of knowing whether the previous generation device from the device you're testing on may still render 60 fps or only renders 20 fps. That's quite possible.

Lastly, to answer your actual question: the only thing you *could* do is to make sure you run the standard (ie non-Retina) resolution Simulator. There's really nothing else you can do besides getting a Mac with a (much) faster CPU.

Answer (score 3):

For graphics, par for course. Dont use simulator for any user experience validation, but stick to devices. Dont waste a minute trying to tweak your workstation settings or looking for ways to improve simulator performance. In any event, your are trying to deploy to devices after all no ?

Some functions work faster on simulator (depending on your workstation of course), like data or computation intensive functions. As always, benchmark on your devices, dont be fooled by 'suitable' simulator performance.

Comment: Hi, I haven't downvoted.. but just to be clear, I have only one iPod and I want to record the screen of it and hence I thought to use the simulator but it works bad. So I want either to understand why or to find another way to record the screen in a professional way.

Comment: @mm24 : Thanks for clarifying the down-vote. I have no specific experience with that specific use case. I suspect there must be ways to do that on devices. Whoever down-voted is better be ready for a healthy surprise if they are using the almighty simulator for graphic performance benchmarking.

Comment: Thanks for your commnent. I will try to find a way and again, I appreciate your help in this and previous answers. Good work :)

Comment: thks. I see some google noise on 'recording' with jailbroken devices. I think that is what my partner did for our promos.

Comment: Thanks.. yeah I saw that too. I wanted to avoid it as I don't know if jailbreaking them will affect my distribution profiles

Comment: More than likely will break your ability to further use the device for development in the normal AppStore/AdHoc pattern (just a guess, but i would put money on it :) ).

Comment: Ok. I am a sole developer so I should spend some time to look for the alternative pattern.. hopefully after release I will be able to collaborate with more experienced people and spend time on this. For today I'll do just a camera recording, which is a shame but seems the only quick way. Thanks for your comments :)

Comment: Looking back at your answer after a year and realize that I hadn't upvoted. Helpful answer. Thanks for your support.